# static ip with wpa2-enterprise and wpa_supplicant

Tags: wifi, static-ip-address, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect to an office network using wpa2-enterprise and set a static IP in it. At the first time I connected with dhcp, got an IP, disconnected and added the following info: wpa_supplicant.conf file:

```
network={
        ssid="myssid"
        key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
        proto=RSN
        pairwise=CCMP TKIP
        group=CCMP TKIP
        identity="my_user"
        password="mypass"
        phase1="peaplabel=0"
        phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
}
```

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.44.72.75
netmask 255.255.255.192
gateway 10.44.72.65
pre-up wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i wlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
post-down killall -q wpa_supplicant
```

After rebooting I see that i got the ip in ifconfig but there is not ping outside nor to the gateway.

What am I missing?